# What is the best way to design a REST web service to accept large String as in JSON format?

Tags: rest

One of the external .NET desktop application is supposed to update our internal MySQL database (Couple of inserts and updates). We’ve agreed to expose a REST web service in order to facilitate this.

I’m thinking of accepting the inputs as a String in JSON format and process inside my REST service. Since there’s lot of values are supposed to be passed into this web service, I’m expecting the inputs in a JSON format without having them in query string or as in params. Is this the best/acceptable way of handling these kind of cases or any other any way of designing this?

Comment: Manmay's got it. Yes, POST JSON in the body to insert, PUT JSON in the body to edit.

Comment: Accepting JSON in the method as a String would be fine, right?

Comment: If you're writing the service as a WCF service, then yes, you'll do a WebInvoke with the POST method, presumably setting input and output formats to JSON, and the method will take some parameters, among which are string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want insert or update a resource through rest then following is the best practices to design it.

**Insert**

Request: POST /resources

Body  {data in json format}

Response  : 201 Created

**Update**

Request : PUT /resources/{id}

Body {data in json format}

Response : 200 OK

Here you can replace "resources" with the term that you want to manage through rest service. And {id} in second case is the identifier which can identify the resource you want to update in your repository.

Comment: Accepting JSON in the method as a String would be fine, right?

Comment: If your method on the server side will accept json as string, then you have to parse it again to build the object. But most of the REST service frameworks do the parsing by default. So you can have the method which will accept an object and your rest framework will do the parsing.

Comment: REST service framework parsing by default means as as it given in this example?

http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program

Comment: Yes This example is perfect.